# Define a unique ID (serial number) based on values in a field

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, fields-attributes, expression

I'm trying to generate a unique serial number for a dataset I have, for example, something like this:

[image]

As shown, I would like to have a serial field, called `SERIAL` in this case, that increments based on the times the value in the column `FIELD NAME` is repeated. The order in which the serial is given is unimportant, I just want to have a unique identifier there, to then add an alphanumeric value based on another table.

Is there any automatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this expression, where you have to replace `color` (end of line 2) with your fieldname:

```
array_find (
    array_sort(array_agg ($id, group_by:="color")),
    $id
)+1
```

[image]

Comment: ¡Thank you so much!, very elegant and straightforward solution

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers). Replace `"color"` with the name of your color field and `'Random points'` with the name of your layer:

```
select  *, 
        row_number() over(partition by "color") as "SERIAL"
from 'Random points'
```

A new temporary layer will be created which you can right click and save:

[image]

Comment: ¡Thanks! Works like a charm, the virtual layer query is a tool I've definitely underused

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `Processing > Toolbox > Vector Table > Add Autoincremental Field` tool.

To use the tool in your situation, set *Field name* = SERIAL, *Start values at* = 1, and *Group values by* = FIELD NAME.

The tool has advanced features including modulus values, NULL values, and sort ordering.

Comment: Wow thank you, wasn't aware there was such a tool, possibly the more noob friendly solution