# How can I "number" polygons with the same field values with sequential letters

Tags: qgis

I am wanting to add numbering with letters for polygons with the same value.

An example would be a field consisting of fruit types:

```
Apple
Apple
Apple
Pear
Pear
Banana
Orange
Orange
Orange
Orange
```

which would be converted to:

```
AppleA
AppleB
AppleC
PearA
PearB
BananaA
OrangeA
OrangeB
OrangeC
OrangeD
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can follow the method in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/450504/98784) and convert the numbers to letters by replacing `+1` with `+65` to generate output from 65-90 (ASCII codes from A-Z) and then putting the numeric result through `char()`. Then concatenate the resulting letter to your field.

```
"YOUR_FIELD" ||
char(
    array_find(
        array_sort(
            array_agg($id, 
                      group_by:="YOUR_FIELD")),
        $id)
    +65)
```

Before and after:

[image]    [image]

Answer (score 9):

You can create a virtual layer with the query:

```
select *,
concat( "Fruit", Char(64 + row_number() over(partition by "Fruit"))) as newfruit
from testpoints
```

[row_number](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) function will enumerate (1,2,3,...) each unique Fruit and
[Char](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char) will replace each number with the [unicode character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Change `"Fruit"` to the name of your field and `testpoints` to the name of your layer.

[image]