QGIS field calculator: grouping incremental values per category2
I have a table with some repeated values in a field.

Is it possible to assign some order value to the repeated values by creating a new field with values starting at one and consecutive integers for each repeated value? No predetermined order is necessary.
Is it possible to establish an order related, for example, to the value of the X coordinates (minimum x=1, second minimum x=2...)

initial TABLE     required TABLE
id  ref           id    ref order
35  A             35    A     1
36  A             36    A     2
37  A             37    A     3
38  B             38    B     1
39  C             39    C     1
40  C             40    C     2
initial TABLE       required TABLE
id  ref x_coord     id  ref x_coord order
35  A     5         35  A     5      2
36  A     3         36  A     3      1
37  A    10         37  A    10      3
38  B     7         38  B     7      1
39  C     5         39  C     5      1
40  C     8         40  C     8      2


Does the Sort and Number plugin help?

The plugin orders all the cells, but is not able to restart order for each repeated value as showned in the required table. Even when you use more than one field to order ( first the field ref, later the field x_coord.

Does this help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376724/incrementing-value-based-on-grouped-field-using-qgis-field-calculator

Or perhaps this?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451343/qgis-field-calculator-grouping-incremental-values-per-category

How about this?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450503/define-a-unique-id-serial-number-based-on-values-in-a-field

the first link is perfect for the first question (ordering without considering X_coords

triyng to solve the second question using your interesting third link (answer 1 and 3)

apparently, it works
array_find (
array_sort       (array_agg ( "x_coord" , group_by:="ref"))
,"x_coord"
)+1
but the easiest way is to use the function Add autoincremental field, grouped by "ref" and sorted by "X_COORDS"

